# Redirection to template instead of rendering inside current template

Tags: meteor

Just wondering if there is a way to redirect to a template through a call inside other html template.  Actually I'm using `{{> myTemplate}}` inside home template but this render "myTemplate" in the same home route ('/').

Why I need that: "myTemplate" need a router param to do all its functions, so I want to call it with something like that:

```
<template name="home">
    {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
        {{#if notEventJoined}}
            {{> findEvent}}
        {{else}}
//*** BELOW HERE: I want to redirect (not just load) to eventContainer template 
// *** and set the getLastEvent param in route. 
            {{REDIRECT eventContainer getLastEventWatched}}  
        {{/if}}
    {{else}}
        Loading...
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

Other way is to do a "temporary template" and call inside the onCreated function of this a `Router.go('eventContainer/'+ getLastEventWatched)` but it seems to me like a workaround.

Comment: You can't redirect inside a blaze template using handlebars, you need to do it in js. If you're using f-r it's just `redirect('path')`

Comment: You could call an empty template (Lets call it redirector) where you put REDIRECT. Then in the onrendered function of that template you can call the actual redirect as @MichelFloyd said. This way you should be able to redirect based on blaze template logic.

Comment: Thank you @Michel and @Jan.  Actually I added the redirection in the same template `onCreated` function.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would work:

Helpers:

```
Template.home.helpers({
    notEventJoined: function(){
        // your conditional stuff
        if(stuff)
           return true;

        Router.go('eventContainer/'+ getLastEventWatched)
    }
});
```

Template:

```
<template name="home">
    {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
        {{#if notEventJoined}}
            {{> findEvent}}
        {{/if}}
    {{else}}
        Loading...
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I finally did was to add the redirection in the same eventContainer template in the onCreated function.

```
Template.eventContainer.onCreated(function() {
  if (!Router.current().params._id) {  // This means the template will be loaded from home so I need to redirect to right path with 
    let lastEvent = Meteor.users.findOne({_id:Meteor.userId()}).profile.lastEvent;
    if (lastEvent){
      Router.go('/eventContainer/'+ lastEvent);
    } else {
      alert("Admin error: No exist previous event");
      Router.go("/findEvent");
    }  
  }
});
```

And let the html as it was:

```
<template name="home">
  {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
    {{#if notEventJoined}}
      {{> findEvent}}
    {{else}}
      {{> eventContainer}}  
    {{/if}}
  {{else}}
    Loading...
  {{/if}}
</template>
```